# How to get all running Python Processes under Windows in an acceptable Time?

Tags: python, process

I would like to get a List of all running Python Processes under Windows 7 (and later on Linux) in an acceptable Time. Based on the Results I would like to start additional new Processes which my main Application depends on.

I tried psutil from https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil:

```
import psutil
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.name == 'python.exe':
        print(process)
```

This gave me good looking Results but running this took about one Minute!

I figured out that both iterating through all Processes with **psutil.process_iter()** and listing all Processes with **psutil.get_pid_list()** are acceptable fast, but obtaining each Processe's Name for the Identification of Python Processes (which I would investigate further with **process.cmdline**) seems to be expensive.

Any Idea how to improve the Speed considerably or another Approach?

Comment: You should improve psutil or use an alternative implementation. The [current one](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/trunk/psutil/arch/mswindows/process_info.c#245) creates a handle, goes through all processes, and only then extracts the name, *for each time* you evaluate `process.name`.

Comment: Why not use a `multiprocessing.Pool` to manage the multiple distinct processes?

Comment: You should create an issue on psutil bug tracker.

Comment: Can one combine this with pdb to check the values of individual variables in a Python process running in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the windows function [`EnumProcesses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (from `Kernel32.dll` or `Psapi.dll` depending on your windows version) directly using [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html).