# Identifying python processes

Tags: python

Is there anyway to uniquely identify python processes running on Windows 7?

I am writing an installer that needs to kill a python process for the installation to continue, the problem is there are multiple python processes running and I need to make sure I kill the correct one!

Comment: Could you modify the code of that python process you want to kill?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554176/how-to-get-all-running-python-processes-under-windows-in-an-acceptable-time or this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326529/python-get-process-names-cpu-mem-usage-and-peak-mem-usage-in-windows

Comment: I need to kill a specific python process as the installer updates this process. There are multiple python processes running ('pythonw.exe').

Comment: @jossgray The only reliable way is to modify this specific process' code so that it will store its own PID somewhere on disk. Then you can easily kill it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you know the command line your program was called with the first time, it might be something like this:

```
for p in psutil.get_process_list():
  if p.cmdline[0].endswith('pythonw.exe') and p.cmdline[1] == 'myscript.py':
    print p.pid
```

Be careful when traversing the cmdlines of various programs though, they have different numbers of elements and can't be reliably unpacked (though I think python 3 has some support for variable length sequence unpacking).  Anyway, worth a try.

Comment: `len(p.cmdline)` would return number of elements in the list on any Python version.

Comment: Definitely, I was just warning against `prog, arg = p.cmdline` blindly.